# Adding Custom post type title to attached images caption attribute in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, metadata, custom-post-type

I trying to resolve an issue that a friend of mine is having with an image heavy Wordpress site.

The site has multiple Custom Post Types and each Post Type has custom fields that allow multiple images to be uploaded.

The problem i'm trying to solve is this; The site has around 40,000 images, most of which are attached to the custom posts mentioned above, these images are used to showcase properties and are combined into preview pages to show to potential clients. Locating the correct images is difficult and i need to add some custom meta data to the images so make them easier to group/navigate.

Ideally i need to add the attachments parent post title into the `alt` or `caption` attributes for every image on the site.

Theoretically this would be done by using a default hook to `add_filter('foo...` I'm just not quite sure how to structure this so that it can run through all old images and future images.

A nudge in the right direction would be very appreciated.

Comment: please accept an answer as your solution if possible, as this issue is so similar to my case. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`WP_Image_Editor` objects that you can perform operations on:

1. wp_save_image_editor_file
2. image_editor_save_pre
3. wp_save_image_editor_file
4. wp_image_editor_before_change

the first hook is triggered when an image is edited (crop/re-size whatever)

the second one is triggered when you crop/rotate the image and press the Save button (and it's a pre-filter)

for the 3rd one it is important to note that you should use `$image->save( $filename, $mime_type );` **inside your callback**, or you will be left with an image that doesn't get saved. And if you want to do so, then better don't return the $saved with no value/NULL.

Comment: Thanks Arash, would you mind elaborating on your answer slightly. Do you think the functionality i need is possible using the hooks you mentioned?